# What is the issue with this XML file, in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, servlets

I don't know much about XML and I am fixing up some code for a Java based application in Eclipse. I'm getting errors here:

[image: Error in code body]

Text marked as an error: `"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd"`

I'm also receiving these errors in the XML file:

[image: Other xml error descriptions]

I would include the entire body of code but it's for work so I'm a bit wary of sharing much of anything. If anyone recognizes any glaring errors, I'd appreciate it. I should add too, that I didn't write this XML file. This is just how it was already written when I received the code.

Also I'm very new at posting to *stack****overflow*** so if this post is just horrible I could take some pointers on that too (lol)

Comment: The xml file does not respect the specification of the document type definition file (dtd) which it refers to. If the app works despite this, it means no part of the code attempts to validate against the dtd, or it simply isn't strictly enforced. I wouldn't bother touching old stuff like that unless there are problems with it.

Comment: @zx485 Please ask for the additional providing of the code/text. Removing of the screenshot because your comment has been read as "text instead of image" would make the question unanswerable. I for myself simply use OCR to get the text that I need to answer the question (see my answer below).

Comment: @zx485 You and others have closed this question because of _"This question needs debugging details"_ but the answer (see below) proves otherwise.

Comment: @howlger: Well, you convinced me. The decision was overhasty. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced DTD file [`http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd) is not a DTD file, but a text file with the following content:

```
The file named http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd
has been renamed to http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
in the most current version of the specification.
Please update your application to use the new name.
```

So the solution is to replace `http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd` with `http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd`.